# How to update cell in Google App Script after it has been filtered

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, lodash

I have the following scripts which are getting data from the Transactions tab of the sample spreadsheet and then running the logic in sumActual such as grouping and setting values in sumActual tab.  This is all working great.

However at the end of the function sumActual where I've noted  // set transactions processed.  I'd like to set the todays date in column "T" to mark the line processed.  However I need to use " const filterProcessedTransactions " from sumActuals because it filters out those rows which have already been processed. I"m not quite sure how to do that.

Any help would be great.

Sample Sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17SId7mIzO3hVOC36Nq40O0bjPS5YfGOX4wsMU1NlbCU/edit?usp=sharing

```js
function sumActual () {
  const _ = LodashGS.load()
  eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment-with-locales.min.js').getContentText())

  const transactions = getTransactions()
  // console.log({ transactions })

  const filterProcessedTransactions = _.filter(transactions, (o) => {
    return !moment(o.Processed).isValid()
  })
  // console.log({ filterProcessedTransactions })

  // Group By Category
  const grouped = _.groupBy(filterProcessedTransactions, (o) => {
    return [o.Category, o.Year, o.Month]
  })
  // console.log({ grouped })

  // sum amount
  const result = _.map(grouped, function (value, key) {

    const d = value[0].Month + '/1/' + value[0].Year
    const startOf = moment(d).format('MM/DD/YYYY')
    const valid = moment(startOf).isValid()
    // console.log({ d, startOf, valid })

    return {
      category: value[0].Category,
      month: value[0].Month,
      year: value[0].Year,
      amount: _.reduce(value, function (total, o) {
        return Math.abs(total + o.Amount)
      }, 0),
      startofMonth: startOf
    }
  })
  // console.log({ result })

  // lookup, merge, sum and update sumActuals
  const obj = result.reduce((o, { category, amount, startofMonth }) => (o[startofMonth + category] = amount, o), {})
  console.log({ obj })

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sumActual')
  const [[, ...header], , ...values] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()
  const res = values.map(([h, ...v]) => v.map((f, j) => {
    const key = Utilities.formatDate(header[j], Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'MM/dd/yyyy') + h
    return obj[key] ? obj[key] + f : f
  }))
  console.log({ res })

  sheet.getRange(3, 2, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res)

  // set transactions processed
  
}
```

```js
function getTransactions () {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const transactionSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Transactions')
  const lastRow = transactionSheet.getLastRow()
  const lastColumn = transactionSheet.getLastColumn()
  const values = transactionSheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, lastColumn).getValues()
  const [headers, ...originalData] = values.map(([, b,, d, e,,,,,,,,,,, p, q, r, s, t]) => [b, d, e, p, q, r, s, t])
  const res = originalData.map(r => headers.reduce((o, h, j) => Object.assign(o, { [h]: r[j] }), {}))
  return res
}
```

[image]

Comment: That's the problem with using the filter function when you are going to need the connection between index and start row in order to obtain new row down stream.  I would probably avoid the use of .filter method in that situation so that I can maintain the connection between startrow index and current row.

Comment: How might you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Sample Solution:

The simplest way, if you are willing to treat all transactions ran by the script as processed, is to set the column values directly:

This function should do that:

```
function setTransactionsProcessed () {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const transactionSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Transactions')
  const lastRow = transactionSheet.getLastRow()
  const lastColumn = transactionSheet.getLastColumn()
  const range = transactionSheet.getRange(2,lastColumn,lastRow-1)
  const processedArr = range.getValues();
  for (i = 0; i < processedArr.length; i++) {
    if (processedArr[i] == '') {
      const d = new(Date);
      processedArr[i][0] = d;
    }
  }
  range.setValues(processedArr);
}
```

And this will be called after filtering out already processed transactions:

```
  const transactions = getTransactions()
   console.log({ transactions })

  const filterProcessedTransactions = _.filter(transactions, (o) => {
    return !moment(o.Processed).isValid()
  })
   console.log({ filterProcessedTransactions })

  setTransactionsProcessed();

  // Group By Category
  const grouped = _.groupBy(filterProcessedTransactions, (o) => {
    return [o.Category, o.Year, o.Month]
  })
  // console.log({ grouped })
```

**Sample Output:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Curious wouldn’t there be performance concerns the more transactions there are? Say running through 10,15,20 thousand rows?

Comment: There should be minimal performance concerns as there are only two calls, getValues and setValues regardless of the size of the sheet.

Comment: Thanks I tested it and it is super fast as you mentioned.  One question however in the above example i set the dates for rows 2 to 10 manually and then did a log of inside if (processedArr[i] ... to visualize what it was running on.  Why would i equal 9 for row 11?  I thought maybe 10 because of the header row but was surprised with 9.  Just tryin to understand, thanks for the example and feedback.

Comment: Because JavaScript indexes start with 0. row 2 = processedArr[0], so on.

Answer (score 0):

#### Preserving the original index

You can do it this way and preserve the original index by adding an extra column named idx

```
function getTransactions () {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  const transactionSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0')
  const lastRow = transactionSheet.getLastRow()
  const lastColumn = transactionSheet.getLastColumn()
  const values = transactionSheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, lastColumn).getValues()
  const [headers, ...originalData] = values.map(([, b,, d, e,,,,,,,,,,, p, q, r, s, t]) => [b, d, e, p, q, r, s, t])
  const res = originalData.map((r,i) => headers.reduce((o, h, j) => Object.assign(o, { [h]: r[j],idx:i }), {}))
  return res;
}
```

Comment: I don't know about the lodash part because I never use it.

Comment: If peformance is an issue because of data length then I'd  probably drop the map and the reduce in getTransactions and push i onto the end of each one during the filter function which is done later.  That way the i could be preserved to recalc the rows.

Comment: So basically by setting idx when getting the transactions, even after filtering I found use the original index to set only those transaction rows that need updating.  That’s the idea correct?  I guess my follow up would be how might I select a row and column using that Index to set the date value?

Comment: row = idx + start row  and start row in this case is 2 I believe. If you wait to do it in the filter and just take values in getTransactions() then figuring out the columns would be easy and I usually take the easy way out especially if it improves performance and I think not do the extra processing in getTransaction will probably improve performance.

Comment: thank you for the explanation.  I ended up going with Carlos example because it was pretty straight forward and as you mentioned simple and fast.  I might use your idx example in the future.  So thank you very much for your time.